Laravel: Failed asserting that actual size 0 matches expected size 4
I am trying to run a quick feature test, to ensure my query string filtering is working
Bu I get a count of 0, like the records don't even exist?
class FilterTicketsTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    /**
     * A basic feature test example.
     */
    public function test_ticket_status_filtering(): void
    {
        Ticket::factory()->count(5)->make();

        Ticket::query()
            ->where('id', 5)
            ->update(['processed' => false]);

        $response = $this->get('/tickets?greater_or_equal=processed,1');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
        $response->assertJsonIsArray('data');

        $this->assertCount(4, $response['data']);
    }
}



make() != create() Look up make vs create in the laravel docs.

In addition to another problem, you faced with that, there is another problem too,
Ticket::query()
->where('id', 5)
->update(['processed' => false]);
this code is not following standard and robust strategy, because you don't know if there is record with id=5 or not. try to get last item instead of getting with id.

https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-factories#instantiating-models
First, we'll use the make method to create models without persisting them to the database:
Make only creates a model in memory. It doesn't insert them into your database.
You want to use create instead.
class FilterTicketsTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    /**
     * A basic feature test example.
     */
    public function test_ticket_status_filtering(): void
    {
        Ticket::factory()->count(5)->create();

        Ticket::query()
            ->where('id', 5)
            ->update(['processed' => false]);

        $response = $this->get('/tickets?greater_or_equal=processed,1');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
        $response->assertJsonIsArray('data');

        $this->assertCount(4, $response['data']);
    }
}


